# Obfuscation error - NoSuchMethodError: android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, inflate, nosuchmethoderror

I'm using LayoutInflater.inflate(int resourceId, ViewGroup group) to inflate some views in my app. But when I run app after obfuscation with proguard I've got this error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30511): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate
```

This is my proguard config:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-ignorewarnings

-libraryjars ...
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class ...

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

I realized, that app crashes on this line:

```
setContentView(mLayoutInflator.inflate(mUiResources.getLayout(mUiResources.getIdentifier("main", "layout", mUiPackage)), null));
```

Whole picture:

```
String mUiPackage = mSettings.getString(mResources.getString(R.string.ui_package), getPackageName());
try {
    mUiResources = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(mUiPackage);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {}

try {
    mUiContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(mUiPackage, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY | Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
    mLayoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) mUiContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {}
setContentView(mLayoutInflator.inflate(mUiResources.getLayout(mUiResources.getIdentifier("main", "layout", mUiPackage)), null));
```

If I changed problem string with

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Problem disappeared. But I need first case. Could you help me find solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you using the cfg file auto-generated by the android tool?

Comment: Yes. I'm using auto generated cfg file with a little bit changes for my libs and some classes to keep public their fields and methods

Comment: Can you post the whole thing, then?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is caused by the option `-ignorewarnings`. You should look at the warnings and try to solve them. If necessary, you can still specify `-dontwarn` for particular classes of which you're sure that they are never actually used during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

That proguard config was generated with an older version of the android SDK.  update to the newest version of the build tools, and from a command line navigate to the root directory of your project (the dir with AndroidManifest.xml in it) and type the following:

> android update project -p .

It should generate a new proguard config file for you-  you can check and make sure that instances of "keepclasseswithmembernames" changes to "keepclasseswithmembers" (I think there are other changes too, but not sure).  See if that fixes it.

Comment: I try, but it didn't help. I decompiled app and found that mLayoutInflator.inflate(mUiResources.getLayout(mUiResources.getIdentifier("main", "layout", mUiPackage)), null) become l1.inflate(XmlRecourceParser, null). And I don't understand why Android did see this method. Method available from 1 api level: [LayoutInflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Comment: I'm running your code with your proguard config, and just not seeing this issue.  Have you tried *without* proguard?  Might be worth verifying that the issue is actually at the obfuscation step.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest ProGuard 4.6. I had similar error when I used the ProGuard that came (even with the latest) Android SDK, but it wasn't the latest ProGuard version. Download and replace it with the proguard folder under [ANDROID_SDK]/tool/proguard. That fixed the problem for me. Not sure if it also works in your case, mine was not related to inflaters, however, I got an error where it just didn't make any sense (with the old ProGuard version).